# pivot_root() in user namespace fails with EINVAL

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, namespace

I want to isolate a potentially dangerous process, without needing root privileges.
However, the syscall `pivot_root` fails with `EINVAL`.

```c
struct clone_args ca = {
    .flags = CLONE_NEWUSER | CLONE_NEWNS,
};
pid = syscall(SYS_clone3, &ca, sizeof ca);
if (pid == 0) {
    mount(NULL, "/", NULL, MS_REC | MS_PRIVATE, NULL);
    mount(".", ".", NULL, MS_BIND | MS_REC, NULL);
    mkdir("./oldroot", 0777);
    syscall(SYS_pivot_root, ".", "./oldroot"); // Fails with EINVAL
}
```

I added `printk` calls in my kernel and recompiled it, and I know it fails at this check: [`if (new_mnt->mnt.mnt_flags & MNT_LOCKED)`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.10/source/fs/namespace.c#L3859).

What does `MNT_LOCKED` mean? What can I do to make `new_mnt` not have this flag? Is it even possible to do that in a user namespace, as a regular user?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the Linux kernel source is that the target of a `pivot_root` must have been mounted from within the user namespace that it's in.

`MNT_LOCKED` seems to primarily be set by `lock_mnt_tree`, which is called in several places where mount namespaces are changed, and are guarded by branches such as `if (child->mnt_parent->mnt_ns->user_ns != user_ns)`.

Comments in `lock_mnt_tree` say this is done to prevent a process in a user namespace from unmounting a mount and seeing what was obscured, as bind mounting an empty directory on top of a sensitive directory is a common way of preventing a container from accessing it.

I believe this can be subverted by waiting until after pivoting to unshare your user namespace. Just don't forget to unshare your mount namespace again while/after unsharing the user namespace so that the user namespace becomes the "owner" of the mount namespace.

Comment: i'm hitting the same check in the kernel but not actually using any user namespace. any other idea what else triggers  it?